# How to get objects from a folder in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to traverse all objects inside a specific **folder** in my S3 bucket. The code I already have is like follows:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder/'):
    do_stuff(obj)
```

I need to use `boto3.resource` and **not** `client`. This code is not getting any objects at all although I have a bunch of text files in the folder. Can someone advise?

Comment: It works for me. It is possible your filter is wrong. Can you try without filter? `for obj in bucket.objects.all()`

Comment: But I need the files to be in the folder

Comment: I am asking you to try without filter just to rule out if you are passing wrong folder name.

Comment: Sure thing. I tried that, and I get this error: `An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`

Comment: That is Django related error.

Comment: The thing is, this error would not be raised if I deleted my folder on S3. Do you know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the Delimiter attribute: `Delimiter = '\'` as you are filtering objects. The rest of the code looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make sure to skip the first file. For some reason it thinks the folder name is the first file and that may not be what you want.

```
    for video_item in source_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="my-folder-name/", Delimiter='/'):
    if video_item.key == 'my-folder-name/':
        continue
    do_something(video_item.key)
```